# Create and easily display cheat sheets (with shortcuts) for any program on Mac

Tags: osx, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently using [CheatSheet.app](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) on OS X (10.9 if that matters). This app displays the shortcuts of the application in focus with a shortcut.

[image: The available shortcuts of the application being used are shown with an overlay]

Sadly, for some programs, IDEs for instance, only a fraction of them are displayed. I'd like to be able to design my own cheat sheet for some programs.

Do any of you know of an alternative to this software that would offer this kind of functionalities? An open-source alternative would be fine too. I may try to implement the functionality myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [KeyCue](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/) for this reason. 
The Software ist not Free but they is expandable- manually and automatically.
Only click "Option-Key" and all Keystrokes are visible.